# Clean python logic to handle all kind of string datetime data

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I am currently getting data from an API and one of the data is a string date & time. However, due to the inconsistent nature of the upstream source (I know i can notify them, but right now it is not feasible), i have various kinds of date time formats.

I have a long method block with multiple try-except block to try to force the string into the datetime strptime with various combinations of known formats. But this is causing the method to grow even longer and longer.

Just wondering if anyone has a brilliant idea how to handle it dynamically?

EDIT: Link to an already answered post is above. But I wont delete this in case someone stumbles on my post instead of the already answered one. Cheers!

Comment: You can delegate the parsing to `dateutil.parser.parse`, then all the code you need is `parse(date_string)` with a single `try-except` block. https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you DeepSpace and olinox14!